# Listview center Text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to center text in a specific column in WPF ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098668/how-to-center-text-in-a-specific-column-in-wpf-listview)

Hi how do we center all the text in the listview items in Wpf?

```
<ListView x:Name="FoldersListView" Margin="57,150,161,139" Style="{DynamicResource ListViewStyle1}" Background="#FFEDDEDE" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Folder" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding Path = FolderPath}" />

                <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = FolderStatus}"/>

            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>            
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have no distinction per column:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Hey thanks it works. I have another question pertaining to this. Since the listview is getting the style from  Style="{DynamicResource ListViewStyle1}" , why doesn't the text center itself when i already specified <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/> UNDER <Style x:Key="ListViewStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">

Comment: @RStyle: Basically because the `ListView.HorizontalContentAlignment` (which your style sets) is independent from `ListViewItem.HorizontalAlignment` (which needs to be set in the `ItemContainerStyle` or in an implicit style for the item container type)

Comment: @RStyle: (Just noticed that i accidentally wrote `HorizontalAlignment`, i of course meant `HorizontalContentAlignment` in both cases, so not to confuse people...)