# UWP: ListView Can't align item in center

Tags: listview, uwp, uwp-xaml, stackpanel

I'm trying to replace my StackPanel with ListView in order to have ItemClick function available.
However, I found out that When I switched from StackPanel to ListView, the Item is not in center anymore.

Before (StackPanel):
[image]

After (ListView):

[image]

Here is the code:

```xml
<SplitView.Pane>
                <Grid Background="{ThemeResource SideBackground}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="#E8E8E8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"/>
                    <Image x:Name="StoreLogo" Width="32" Height="32"></Image>
                    <ListView>
                        <localui:ButtonWithIcon
                                IconContent="&#xE1D3;"
                                Content="书架"
                                Style="{StaticResource TransparentFontButtonStyle}"/>
                        <localui:ButtonWithIcon
                                IconContent="&#xEC27;" 
                                Content="搜索"
                                Style="{StaticResource TransparentFontButtonStyle}"/>
                        <localui:ButtonWithIcon 
                                IconContent="&#xE713;"
                                Content="设置"
                                Style="{StaticResource TransparentFontButtonStyle}"/>
                    </ListView>
                        <localui:ButtonWithIcon
                                IconContent="&#xE13D;"
                                Content="请登录"
                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                Margin="0,0,0,30"
                                Style="{StaticResource RoundFontButtonStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </SplitView.Pane>
```

```
<Style x:Key="TransparentFontButtonStyle" TargetType="localui:ButtonWithIcon">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,30,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="localui:ButtonWithIcon">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="Icon"
                            Text="{Binding IconContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                            FontSize="30"/>
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="Text"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            FontSize="14"
                            Margin="0,18,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to center text in a specific column in WPF ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098668/how-to-center-text-in-a-specific-column-in-wpf-listview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property for ListViewItem With the following code. then the content of ListViewItem will center.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <local:ButtonWithIcon Content="书架" IconContent="&#xE1D3;" />
    <local:ButtonWithIcon Content="搜索" IconContent="&#xEC27;" />
    <local:ButtonWithIcon Content="设置" IconContent="&#xE713;" />
</ListView>
```

After setting above style for `ItemContainer` keep in mind `HorizontalAlignment` property of each element inside `ListView` matters.

That is if `<local:ButtonWithIcon>` has set `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` then it will keep item in center and if it's set to `Stretch` then element inside `ListView` will try to take all available space horizontally. And if not set then element (in your case ButtonWithIcon) will stick to left side.

Comment: He would also need to set `HorizontalAlignment="Center` for-each Button inside OR `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` to fill whole space.

Comment: During the testing, it has same result when  set  `HorizontalContentAlignment` as Stretch or Center. and you could also set `Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"`

Comment: No ! result is not same. as you can see in this attached pic. https://imgur.com/XTRBH9Y

Comment: Please check this [screenshot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlLBgdBasvMrgYYNtoozys31iungsQ?e=5hYcpO) in my side.

Comment: In  `<local:ButtonWithIcon>` you must have mentioned `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` that is then applied to each button inside `ListView`. and obviously changing this value will make different results. That's why i explicitly mentioned alignment property with each button.

Comment: And you could check @Coel's  TransparentFontButtonStyle , he has already set TextBlock `HorizontalAlignment="Center"`.

Comment: Yes. i got it. i just pointed that that alignment makes a difference, In case OP skip that.

Comment: Thanks for  @Rao Hammas 's update, have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks @NicoZhu-MSFT and also Rao Hammas, It works perfectly!

Comment: Welcome sir :) @NicoZhu-MSFT